# How can I get the data of form on submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get the data of form on submit?

```
    import React, { Component }           from 'react';
import Axios                          from 'axios';

class Register extends Component {
    submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = '';
        var data = {
            returnSecureToken:true,
            email:this.email,
            password:this.password
        }
        Axios.post(url,data)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                console.log(err);
            })

    }
    render() {
        var listClasses = "";
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Registrati</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                    <input type="password" className={listClasses} value={this.props.value} placeholder="password" name="password"/>
                    <input type="email" className={listClasses} value={this.props.value} placeholder="email" name="email"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Register;
```

I want to send my data by post. I tried to find into my object ***this*** but I don't see my data after submit.

Comment: Best approach would be to use react dom refs for each form input. https://css-tricks.com/react-forms-using-refs/. Btw in your example you use same value for password and email.

Comment: attach event handler for onchange events in the inputs, which will give you the value via event.target.value that gets passed to the event handler.
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: @oosniss There is no reason to create three event handlers, and no reason to watch them onchange if you only care for their value on form submit.

Comment: Have you tried watching any **Youtube** tutorials? There are countless just for what you ask.

Comment: @AbidHasan I think one of the central tenants of react is that the DOM is not a storage layer; you don't _read_ the DOM, you _synchronize_ the DOM to match your application state. To get their value only on form submit you would need to to just that: _read_ from the DOM, as if it were the source of truth.

Comment: @Tyrsius I admit I am always willing to learn new things, and I understand that the DOM isn't a storage layer. I was perhaps more alluding to using an onBlur event handler? Would that be a better option? Is that more preferable to making `ref`s to each input and reading those?

Comment: Use control inputs. In your code what is the vavlue of `this.email` `this.password` ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to make the component, uncontrolled component and hook up the change event handlers for each field.

Would be better than using `refs` that break the encapsulation.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

class Register extends Component {
  state = {
    emailAddress: '',
    password: ''
  }
  submitHandler = (event) => {
    const {
      emailAddress,
      password
    } = this.state;

    event.preventDefault();
    var url = '';
    var data = {
      returnSecureToken: true,
      email: emailAddress,
      password: password
    }
    Axios.post(url, data)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })

  }

  handlePasswordChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
  }

  handleEmailChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ emailAddress: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    var listClasses = "";
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Registrati</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
          <input onchange={this.handlePasswordChange} type="password" className={listClasses} value={this.props.value} placeholder="password" name="password" />
          <input onchange={this.handleEmailChange} type="email" className={listClasses} value={this.props.value} placeholder="email" name="email" />
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Register;
```